# Add annotations to video player

Tags: annotations, jwplayer, video-player

I am looking for a video player for videos hosted on web site, that supports annotations like youtube. So the basic functionality will be adding an annotation with time, duration, position, size, color, and as a bonus display all annotations as time links to periods of the video.

So now i'm using JW Player for my developing because i like it's features (cross browser, clear api and documentation flash+html5 etc). I have read about popcorn.js and kaltura that can support annotation but i don't find their solutions clear.

What do you think of a solution that can work on both html5 and flash? Is there something "clear" out there or should i develop it on jwplayer as plugin? (i'm thinking of storing in xml files, and display them with jquery on video area).

Comment: You would need to develop a custom JavaScript plugin to do something like this. We have a SDK available here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/

Answer (score 0):

(I do not have the reputation to comment this)
The approach I am using is to check every few milliseconds (e.g. 200ms), whether an annotation with its start and end time should be activated or not.

```
for(a in annotations){
 if( playbackTime < a.end AND playbackTime >= a.start){
  a.activate()
 }else{
  a.deactivate()
 }
}
```